# Need to create a pull request but entirely different commit histories and --allow-unrelated-histories causing lots of conflicts

Tags: git

I want to create a Pull Request for the sole purpose of being able to get someone to review my code. My branch new-branch has an entirely different commit history from master as I had earlier done a force push (something I can't and don't want to change)

I created a new branch from master 'test-branch' and did a `git merge new-branch --allow-unrelated-histories`

This led to a lot of conflicts which I don't have the time to resolve.
I don't care about deleting or rewriting the code in master
Please help

Comment: Interesting question :). what is the scenario such that unrelated code is in the same repository? Rebasing your changes on top of master would result in clean and common histories, if there are no/few common files between the two.

Comment: The phrase *don't care about* implies that it's OK to destroy `master` entirely. Did you mean that, or did you mean *don't care to*, i.e., *am unwilling to* destroy or rewrite `master`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in a scenario that you have branched out from master and forced pushed in such a way that you have more important code in your branch than the master - and you need your branch to be prominent.

And based on the following:

> I don't care about deleting or rewriting the code in master

1. Create an empty branch

   ```
   git checkout --orphan empty-branch
   ```
2. Create a pull request from `new-branch` to `empty-branch` and let the discussion happen. Optionally, you can "sqash" merge the `new-branch` to another temporary branch if you want to hide all the different commits.

   ```
   [git merge --squash new-branch]
   ```
3. Finally, force push the empty branch to the master after merging the pull request.

   ```
   git push -f origin empty-branch:master
   ```

Comment: Thank you summarizing the issue 
But I don't want to push the changes - I want to be able to create a pull request so that someone else can review the code officially.

Comment: Yes - I realized this and was editing the answer while you were typing the comment.